# setting up wsgi like app engine

Tags: mod-wsgi

I have been using wsgi on app engine to great success and now i want to use a similar setup on a fedora core 8 machine. how do i go about doing it?

I am using yum and i have installed mod_wsgi but i don't know how to implement it. I have mod_python working already

Thanks

Comment: 14 has been released. That makes 8 three years old, and almost 2 years unsupported.

Comment: yes i didn't realize that. swapped it for a centOS 5.4 server which plugged in so easy to my EBS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSGI is a [specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/), not a framework. Consider learning something a little less low-level, such as Flask or Django.

[mod_wsgi configuration directives](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives) for httpd

[Paste Deployment](http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/), a standalone WSGI container

[WSGI tutorials](http://wsgi.org/wsgi/Learn_WSGI) if you insist on learning bare WSGI

Comment: thanks for the pointers. what i meant was that i wanted to use the url parser that appengine wsgi has under the 'application' object: application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', pageIndex)], debug=True) and so on.

Comment: You mean routing. Try Routes then.

Answer (score 1):

Find the `<VirtualHost>` section for the site you want in your Apache config and add:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /foo /path/to/your/app/foo.py
```

Now you've made a mapping between URL paths starting with /foo and the script foo.py. For `mod_wsgi`, you just need to have that script leave a WSGI application callable under the name `application`, eg:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8')])
    return ['<p>Hello world</p>']
```

and that's it. If you've already got a WSGI application object you should be able to drop it right in.